# Map within filter in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I filter within mapping ?

Example :

```
test1 = sc.parallelize(Array(('a', (1,Some(4)), ('b', (2, Some(5)), \
('c', (3,Some(6)), ('d',(0,None))))
```

What I want :

```
Array(('a', (1,Some(4)), ('b', (2, Some(5)), \ ('c', (3,Some(6)), \ 
('d',(613,None))))
```

What I tried (I've change the 0 by 613) :

```
test 2 = test1.filter(value => value._2._1 == 0).mapValues(value => 
(613, value._2))
```

But it returns only :

```
Array('d',(613,None))
```

Comment: You don't need the filter, just move the condition into map and add else to return original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` with pattern matching:

```
test1.map { 
    case (x, (0, y)) => (x, (613, y)) 
    case z => z 
}.collect
// res2: Array[(Char, (Int, Option[Int]))] = Array((a,(1,Some(4))), (b,(2,Some(5))), (c,(3,Some(6))), (d,(613,None)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test1.map{
  case (a, (0, b)) => (a, (613, b))
  case other => other
}
```